# Content export, reinstall and content import

Tags: content, import, export

I run a WordPress site and I need to change the theme to a new, faster one. However, when I install the new theme and Import demo content, the site doesn't present well at all.

I'm thinking of a way of doing a fresh install without losing my pages and posts. My question is: If I export my content, run a fresh install, and Import back the content, will the post and pages permalinks stay the same? Is this going to impact my SEO negatively?

Comment: One of the pages imported by the demo content might be for the homepage. However, there is a chance that is hasn't been as homepage in your settings > reading setting.

Comment: Normally permalinks shouldn't be affected by that. But other things may be affected by that, display-wise, depending how different your new theme is from your current theme, feature-wise.

Comment: @leymannx, thank you. That's what I wanted to know. Still not sure on the SEO though. How will search engines regard the site/pages/posts after the reinstall?

Comment: SEO never is a sure thing ;) Normally they should be doing just what they did before: Finding the posts/pages at the place where they are indexed already. Maybe they'll recognize improvements from your new theme's responsiveness or loading time. But this will take time before you benefit from it. Maybe make an SEO audit now, using Google Search Console, and then do it again after the relaunch. And better be prepared and keep a full copy of your complete old website's files and database at backhand if something goes wrong.

Comment: Surely will do, @leymannx. Thanks for your time and help. I really do appreciate.